# Parsing Map to JSON using JSON Simple

Tags: java, json, servlets

I am using `Gson` library to convert Map to JSON. But requirement is to use  `json-simple-1.1.1`. I google for solution but my bad luck couldn't get solution.

I want to use JSON Simple to achieve following operation:

```
/** Converting Map to JSON and sending response back to view */
private void write(HttpServletResponse response, Map<String, Object> map) throws IOException {
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(map)); 
}
```

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use

```
//import org.json.simple.JSONValue;

String jsonText = JSONValue.toJSONString(map);
System.out.print(jsonText);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using this :

```
new JSONObject(map);
```

Comment: I got this error: "The method write(int) in the type PrintWriter is not applicable for the arguments (JSONObject)"

Answer (score 1):

Try it, this will work:

```
org.json.simple.JSONObject jsonObj = new org.json.simple.JSONObject();
String jsonStr = jsonObj.toJSONString(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

response.getWriter().write(JSONValue.toJSONString(map));